# Oracle extended properties available?

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I am trying to understand if it is possible to use the MS SQL Server concept of "extended properties" in Oracle database?

An explanation/illustration of SQL Server's extended properties is found here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5384/working-with-sql-server-extended-properties/ 
Essentially it allows for developers/dbas or other concerned individuals to add (and read) meta data about database objects.

Examples could be: related project ID/Name, originating Business Area, description of object, intended use, or whatever else you can think of.

I realise that the Comments field/attribute for db objects can be filled up with all sort of information (up to 4000 characters), but it would be useful to have separate fields (e.g. as found in the "details" pane of SQL Developer when selecting a table)

I hope the above is clear enough,

Many thanks,

B

Comment: Suggestion raised https://community.oracle.com/ideas/23364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are the only additional metadata that you can attach to a table in Oracle (and it's limited to tables, views and columns).

The only other solution I can think of is to create your own stored procedure `sp_addextendedproperty` that stores this information in a separate table.

However, you however have any support in the standard SQL tools to display those properties "automatically".

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - I'll accept it as it confirms what I suspected and that I will indeed need to build my own meta data repository.
I understand that some products (Architecture type prods such as er-studio etc) do the trick, but for devs it's often a "step-too-far-removed-from-the-action", they generally prefer to stick to their fav SQL tool and peruse the table comments/extended props.